# "No matching constructor for initialization of. . ."

Tags: c++

I recognize that this type of question has been asked, and I looked at those responses but still think I'm missing something.  I get this "No matching constructor error", because I don't have a constructor, but that being said, everything that I looked at about constructors said that you need them if you don't already include the variable names inside the class.  But I already did that, so do I need a constructor?  If I do, what should it look like then?  I'm new to C++, taking a class, and this is for an assignment.

Here's my sensor_node.h file with the class declaration:

```
#ifndef SENSORNODE_H
#define SENSORNODE_H

#include <iostream>

class LOCATION {
    float lat, longi, height;

public:
    LOCATION (float lat, float longi, float height);
    void setx(float xx);
    void sety(float yy);
    void setz(float zz);
    void print();
};

class SensorNode {
    char* NodeName;
    int NodeID;
    LOCATION Node1;
    float batt;
    int func;


public:
    SensorNode(char *n, float x, float y, float z, int i, float ah);
    void print();
    void setOK(int o);
    int getOK();
    void setLOC(float longi, float lat, float h);
};

#endif /* defined(__Project_3__sensor_node__) */
```

And here's my main.cpp with the error (On the line that says "LOCATION"):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


#include "sensor_node.h"

int main() {
    LOCATION a; SensorNode s1("Pulse",15.9,-30.1,0,157,2.0);
    int hold;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you so have a constructor: `LOCATION (float lat, float longi, float height)`. Since it is the only one, C++ tries to apply it. However, you did not provide any parameters, thus this constructor does not match.

Comment: So does this mean I need another constructor?  My instructor made this line :     LOCATION a; SensorNode s1("Pulse",15.9,-30.1,0,157,2.0);
And I see that it's arguments don't match the constructor.  But I don't really understand.  Am I supposed to make another constructor? Or is that calling a function that I haven't built yet?

Comment: You could either give `a` three parameters (e.g., `LOCATION a(1.2,3.4,5.6);` in ), or you can provide a default constructor `LOCATION();` in your class definition.

Answer (score 0):

You have a constructor for `LOCATION` (why the inconsistent capitalisation, incidentally?) that takes three floats, but the line `LOCATION a` tries to call the default constructor, which you haven't defined.